# Telnet - Connecting to Website Servers

Tags: batch-file, cmd, gmail, port, telnet

I don't use Telnet a lot so I will need the answer explained really clearly and simple. I want to connect to a website (gmail) with Telnet. I have looked at this post but I am too new to Telnet to understand it:

[Send email from gmail using Telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288292/send-email-from-gmail-using-telnet)

So basically, I want to use gmail in Telnet. I don't know what code I need. I also don't know what to do before I start (I heard something about "enabling port 25"). So please just tell me exactly what code I can use (batch file) or what steps I should directly in CMD. Please post an answer as an answer and tell me if this question is better fit for SuperUser. I have looked at multiple StackOverflow answers to this but they were to confusing or not exactly what I wanted. I also found this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123686(v=exchg.160).aspx
and all was working fine with that method up until "MAIL FROM: sender@server.com" when I did that I got a syntax error. Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email using simple SMTP commands via Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046135/how-to-send-email-using-simple-smtp-commands-via-gmail) The short version is "you can't." Also, I'm not sure why you would even want to.

Comment: First things first. **You have to go to GMail Options and enable POP3 access** or nothing will work.

Comment: I looked at that link and it was confusing and not exactly what I was looking for. I also found this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123686(v=exchg.160).aspx It helped me up until the "MAIL FROM: sender@server.com" which gave me a syntax error. P.S. I am using this for my .bat OS.

Comment: @ACatInLove Where do I change the POP3 options?

Comment: See my answer at another question that became active for some reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288292/send-email-from-gmail-using-telnet#comment82294794_19288292.

Comment: @ACatInLove Alright, so I did that and I got an error on line 22 character 1 saying "The server response was not available" (80040211). Also, I tried this method: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123686(v=exchg.160).aspx and it was working until "MAIL FROM: sender@server.com" when I did that command I got a syntax error. Could you check that link out and tell me how my syntax was incorrect even though I did it the same way that they did. P.S. I am running Windows XP Home SP3.

Comment: Try putting the account email address for that line. SNMP used to have no security and so spammers used them. Now they are picky about what mail they send. And there will probably be gmail email you need to respond to.

Comment: On line 22? That is "emailObj.Send". Why would I replace that with an email adress?